# The system is out of resources. Consult the following stack trace for details. java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, maven

I get the following stack trace when I run `mvn clean install package`

```
The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:615)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBinary(Attr.java:3033)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:1785)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
```

Here is a subsection of the stdout/stderr from Maven

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.903 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-09T03:55:20+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/596M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project test: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Can someone teach/help me how to resolve this?

Comment: @Polygnome sadly, it didnt work. im still getting the same error

Comment: Upgrade the maven-compiler-plugin to the most recent version https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ which JDK version do you run on?

Comment: Can you run add a -X flag at the end of your mvn command ( mvn clean -X ) and update your original post more pertinent information.  Also what JDK version is your application, what maven version are you using, and what JDK version is maven using

Answer (score 0):

You can change the stack size by modifying the flags sent to java during invokation.

https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-configure-stack-sizes#custom

```
java -Xss2m
```

This would give you 2 mb of stack size (instead of the default 1mb).

You can add `-Xss2m` (or whatever you need - experimentation will be required) to your `MAVEN_OPTS` environment:

```
env MAVEN_OPTS="-Xss2m $MAVEN_OPTS" mvn ...
```

Comment: i tried doing it, the memory went up but still compilation failure

Comment: How high did you set the limit?  It can go higher than `2m` -- to at least `1g`.